# mimic ' group by' and window function logic in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a large `csv` file with the columns `id,time,location`. I made it an RDD, and want to compute some aggregated metrics of the `trips`, when a trip is defined as a time-contiguous set of records of the same id, separated by at least 1 hour on either side. I am new to spark. ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051669/sql-query-to-group-by-maximal-sets-of-a-column-having-inner-consecutive-distance))

To do that, I think to create an RDD with elements of the form `(trip_id,(time, location))` and use `reduceByKey` to calculate all the needed metrics.

To calculate the `trip_id`, i try to implement the SQL-approach of the linked question, to make an indicator field of whether the record is a start of a trip, and make a cumulative sum of this indicator field. This does not sound like a distributed approach: is there a better one?

Furthermore, how can I add this indicator field? it should be 1 if the time-difference to the previous record of the same `id` is above an hour, and 0 otherwise. I thought of at first doing `groupBy` id and then sort in each of the values, but they will be inside an Array and thus not amenable to `sortByKey`, and there is no `lead` function as in SQL to get the previous value.

**Example** of the suggested aforementioned approach: for the RDD

```
(1,9:30,50)
(1,9:37,70)
(1,9:50,80)
(2,19:30,10)
(1,20:50,20)
```

We want to turn it first into the RDD with the time differences,

```
(1,9:30,50,inf)
(1,9:37,70,00:07:00)
(1,9:50,80,00:13:00)
(2,19:30,10,inf)
(2,20:50,20,01:20:00)
```

(The value of the earliest record is, say, scala's `PositiveInfinity` constant)

and turn this last field into an indicator field of whether it is above 1, which indicates whether we start a trip,

```
(1,9:30,50,1)
(1,9:37,70,0)
(1,9:50,80,0)
(2,19:30,10,1)
(2,20:50,20,1)
```

and then turn it into a `trip_id`

```
(1,9:30,50,1)
(1,9:37,70,1)
(1,9:50,80,1)
(2,19:30,10,2)
(2,20:50,20,3)
```

and then use this `trip_id` as the key to aggregations.

The preprocessing was simply to load the file and delete the header,

```
val rawdata=sc.textFile("some_path")
def isHeader(line:String)=line.contains("id")
val data=rawdata.filter(!isHeader(_))
```

**Edit**

While trying to implement with spark SQL, I ran into an error regarding the time difference:

```
val lags=sqlContext.sql("
  select time - lag(time) over (partition by id order by time) as diff_time from data
");
```

since spark doesn't know how to take the difference between two timestamps. I'm trying to check whether this difference is above 1 hour.

It Also doesn't recognize the function `getTime`, that I found online as an answer, the following returns an error too (`Couldn't find window function time.getTime`):

```
val lags=sqlContext.sql("
  select time.getTime() - (lag(time)).getTime() over (partition by id order by time) 
  from data
");
```

Even though making a similar `lag` difference for a numeric attribute works:

```
val lag_numeric=sqlContext.sql("
select longitude - lag(longitude) over (partition by id order by time) 
from data");  //works
```

Spark didn't recognize the function `Hours.hoursBetween` either. I'm using `spark 1.4.0`.

I also tried to define an appropriate user-defined-function, but UDFS are oddly not recognized inside queries:

```
val timestamp_diff: ((Timestamp,Timestamp) => Double) =
    (d1: Timestamp,d2: Timestamp) => d1.getTime()-d2.getTime()
val lags=sqlContext.sql("select timestamp_diff(time,lag(time)) 
over (partition by id order by time) from data");
```

> So, how can spark test whether the difference between timestamps is above an hour?

**Full code**:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext._
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext//For window functions
import java.util.Date
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Record(id: Int, time:Timestamp, longitude: Double, latitude: Double)
val raw_data=sc.textFile("file:///home/sygale/merged_table.csv")

val data_records=
                    raw_data.map(line=>
                           Record( line.split(',')(0).toInt,
                                   Timestamp.valueOf(line.split(',')(1)),
                                   line.split(',')(2).toDouble,
                                   line.split(',')(3).toDouble 
                                  ))                                                                                     

val data=data_records.toDF()
data.registerTempTable("data")
val lags=sqlContext.sql("
  select time - lag(time) over (partition by id order by time) as diff_time from data
");
```

Comment: Spark supports window functions since 1.4 and there are quite a few similar questions on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping timeseries data to previous datapoints and averages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526328/mapping-timeseries-data-to-previous-datapoints-and-averages)

Comment: But I'm not using Spark SQL. I'm not dealing with tables here, but with tuples. (That only represent rows logically)

Comment: You can covert to data frame, use window functions, extract rdd. And some other alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31538829/1560062

Comment: Thank you. What about efficiency? Are the HiveContext window functions as fast as working programmatically with tuples, like in your 'alternative' link? Also, I didn't succeed in using the lag from the duplicate question. Added details in the question above.